# Need to add a reference axis for the fabricJS objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Creating an editing tool using fabricJS.. I want to add a reference axis to help user to align the object when the object is getting rotated. I need something like what is in the picture->
[image: red-lines describe the reference axis]

Basically I want to know how to modify the selection to add those axis

*I don't know why people downvote without bothering to even give a probable solution. The question I have doesn't require a snippet neither the solution is available elsewhere!

Comment: Each question deserve a snippet for helping who wants to answer. Unless you have the answer ready ( improbable ) for who wants to try to answer anyway, the snippet is the starting point.

Comment: Downvoted also but bothered to answer. There should not be so big difference of effort from who ask and who answers. I had to prepare a full snippet while i could have had just modified your.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can modify a default fabricjs function mantaining the original behaviour and adding something on top of it.

```js
var img02URL = 'http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg';
var originalDrawBorders = fabric.Object.prototype.drawBorders;

fabric.Object.prototype.drawBorders = function(ctx, styleOverride) {
originalDrawBorders.call(this, ctx, styleOverride);
      var wh = this._calculateCurrentDimensions(),
          strokeWidth = 1 / this.borderScaleFactor,
          width = wh.x + strokeWidth + 40,
          height = wh.y + strokeWidth + 40;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(-width / 2, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(width/ 2, 0);
      ctx.moveTo(0, -height/2);
      ctx.lineTo(0, height/2);
      ctx.stroke();
}

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setZoom(0.5)

fabric.Image.fromURL(img02URL, function(oImg) {
    oImg.scale(.40);
    oImg.left = 180;
    oImg.top = 0;
    canvas.add(oImg);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```css
#c {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.17/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```